# Creating a Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I am having an issue and hoping someone might have a suggestion that will help me. 
I am trying to create a child theme so that I can make some changes to some styles and also some page functions in my Wordpress v 4.1.1

My issue is when I activate my child theme my site goes all blank (white) and all that is visible is the wordpress admin panel toolbar at the top of the screen.
I followed the instructions here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

My parent theme is called qk_theme which is located at 
wp-contents/themes/qk_element

So i created a new folder which is
wp-contents/themes/qk_element-child

in my new folder I have a style.css file that contains

```
/*
  Theme Name:   qk_element Child
  Theme URI:    example.com
  Description:  A child theme based on qk_elemen
  Author:       Jay
  Author URI:   none
  Template:     qk_element
  Version:      1.0
  Tags:         Light, Gray, White, Custom Background, Custom Menu, Editor Style, Featured Images, Flexible Header, Full Width Template, Microformats, Post Formats, RTL Language Support, Sticky Post, Theme Options, Translation Ready
  Text Domain:  qk_element-child
```

*/

Then I have a functions.php file in it I have

```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
   function theme_enqueue_styles() 
 {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
     array('parent-style')
    );
 }
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Does the "qk_element" theme work on it's own without the child?

Comment: Yes the qk_element theme works fine on its own (without the child theme).

Comment: does it work without the functions.php present in child theme? Is your style.css still valid after you changed it?

Comment: no even if I delete the functions.php file and then activate the theme the site still goes all blank.

Comment: Open wp-config.php and add define('WP_DEBUG', true); to turn on debug mode. After this is done, do any errors appear on the site?